# Why is my ajax form not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get this ajax form just to return a success message but only ever get the error 'film id is required'. (Eventually I will insert the form values into a mysql database). Please can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Many thanks.

The form

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<div id="film_id-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="film_id">Film_id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="film_id"    placeholder="film_id">        
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
</form>
```

Process.php

```
<?php

$errors         = array();  
$data           = array();      
$film_id = $_POST['film_id'];


if (empty($_POST['film_id']))
    $errors['film_id'] = 'Film Id is required.';


if ( ! empty($errors)) {


    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] ='sucess!';
}


echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The javascript.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
    $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text
    var formData = {
        'film_id'               : $('input[film_id=film_id]').val(),
    };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', 
        encode      : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {


            console.log(data); 


            if ( ! data.success) {

                // handle errors
                if (data.errors.film_id) {
                    $('#film_id-group').addClass('has-error');
        $('#film_id-group').append('<div class="help-  block">' +   data.errors.film_id + '</div>'); 
                }                             

            } else {

                $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

            }
        })

        .fail(function(data) {

        });

    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

Comment: Have you checked `$('input[film_id=film_id]')`? Seems like it should be `$('input[name=film_id]')`

Comment: basic debugging: `console.log(formData)` in JS, `var_dump($_POST)` in php, see what's being sent out, see what's being received.

Comment: Also when use js objects remove leading coma after last attribute, else you will have troubles with IE

Comment: Since your form has no name, how are your sure that JQuery is sending the right form contents?  It might be sending nothing at all.

Comment: $('input[name=film_id]')    fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
'film_id': $('input[film_id=film_id]').val(),
```

in your AJAX `formData` object should be:

```
'film_id': $('input[name=film_id]').val()
```

(Also make sure to remove the trailing comma, because there is no element after it.)

Your code is searching for an `<input>` element like the following:

```
<input film_id="film_id" />
```

This is incorrect. Your selector should have `name` as the attribute name, not `film_id`.

Therefore, because there is no such element, this would send nothing to the PHP file (""), which would evaluate as false, as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).